“Waiting” for the answer to the ultimate questions
The desire to know the answers to ultimate questions like “Who am I?”, “What is reality?”, and “What is the mind?” has been haunting me throughout my life.
From my understanding, current philosophy and science cannot adequately explain these questions. In fact, I think even articulating some of these ultimate questions is extremely challenging for human language. Therefore, it seems to me that it will likely take a very long time—possibly even beyond my lifetime—to find answers, if ever. AI appears to be developing rapidly, which might unexpectedly accelerate our progress.
If one’s life goal is to understand these ultimate questions and their solutions, should they focus on longevity in order to wait for humanity to develop the necessary technology, philosophy, or language? The reason one might avoid directly researching these topics themselves is that the risk of accidental death (such as from a car crash or disease) remains high, and individual contributions to cutting-edge research are often minor. This might mean that, to maximize the chance of eventually knowing the answers, “waiting” could be more effective than directly tackling these questions—assuming that the answers, rather than the pursuit of knowledge itself, are what matter most to them.
Moreover, to achieve longevity, one might need to accumulate wealth to access the best medical resources, or even longevity technology if it becomes available. They might also want to develop political power to stay informed and ensure their safety.
From an ethical standpoint, the above approach could be seen as quite selfish or even “evil.” However, from a "practical" standpoint, does it seem reasonable and actionable?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Welcome! Seems you've been thinking deeply. Philosophy SE is a Q&A site, and not a general forum for discussions like thephilosophyforum.com. As such, posts that don't fit the Q&A format are closed, so don't take that personally. When you get a chance, review the FAQs on the Help Site philosophy.stackexchange.com/help and if you have any questions, you can also jump over to the meta site philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com

@JD Hello, I wonder why exactly this question does not fit the Q&A format. From my understanding, it might be because the last “question” is asking whether the aforementioned “strategy” is practical, which could sound opinion-based. Is that correct? If so, could you suggest a way to modify the question to make it fit?

The better place to ask this question is Philosophy Meta. I'd go over there, post the question, and tag me, and I'll try to give a few pointers if you're interested in learning from the community.

@JD I posted it. I don't know how to tag you. Would appreciate it if you could tell me the difference between the two sites and/or how to learn more from the community.

@JD Meta is purely for discussion of the functioning of this site, rather than discussing philosophy itself. For philosophy questions that don't belong on the main site (particularly more open-ended or discussion-based ones), [chat] (e.g. the main philosophy chat room) would be a better recommendation.

@NotThatGuyOh? In practice, many people have asked and received guidance for using the site there.

@JD "guidance for using the site" - yes. Philosophy questions like "should they focus on longevity" - no. It's possible that there was a miscommunication about what exactly you were recommending that OP do and what help you were suggesting they provide - I read your comment as OP did - that you're recommending they ask this question as is on Meta (which they did). But maybe you were instead replying to "could you suggest a way to modify the question", in which case, fair enough.

Well, the sticking point here is that knowing is largely irrelevant. We need to understand. If someone could tell the answers to these 'ultimate questions' we would likely find them incomprehensible, because we never properly understood the questions to begin with. Understanding takes effort; we can't wait passively for someone to give it to us. We have to reach for it, and encounter it: to break through the hard, dead shell of knowledge to get to the vital living meat of understanding.
That's one of the odd paradoxes of meditation. From the outside it seems like the ultimate form of waiting; from the inside it's the ultimate form of encountering.
My rule of thumb, for what it's worth: the means ultimately justify the ends. It doesn't matter how good, noble, important, or valuable the ends might seem. If the means used are contemptible, the ends reached will be corrupt and without value. Keep your eye on the horizon, sure, but keep your hand on the plow and guide it well, or you'll never grow anything but weeds.

+1 for the wise saying :-)

I agree that understanding is necessary and is likely to take much effort. What I try to stress in my question is that, given our (humans’) current language and thinking level, I doubt whether it’s possible for anyone to have enough time to try to understand a non-trivial portion of the ultimate question, or even really get closer to the answer. I would even risk overestimating my ignorance and claim that a lifetime would be too short for the quest. Therefore, my intuition is that longevity might be a necessary “initial step” for making non-trivial progress.

@DanielMendoza: Difficult trade secret: understanding doesn't take copious time. Understanding is a world-shift, like a chunk of ice falling from a glacier. A sudden 'crack', a whoosh of incidental thoughts and emotions, and it's done. You can wait for that 'crack' or seek it out, up to you. But the real point here is that no one and nothing can give it to you. Waiting for it to come from outside is like waiting for a bus to pick you up in your living room.

@DanielMendoza: I understand what you're wresting with, and I have sympathy; it's a very, very common direction for worry. But what you'll eventually have to get is the idea that 'time' is a function of the thinking, planning mind; it's the ultimate incomprehensible thing that the mind is desperate to control. Time is the boogieman.

@DanielMendoza: Right now I'm sure it feels like you're stuck in a rowboat in the middle of the sea, trying to figure out which way and how hard to paddle, where any choice you make seems like it will take too long and be too hard. But the odd thing about this case is that getting where you want to go means coming back to where you are, just with a different perspective. paddling longer doesn't intrinsically translate to better.


The desire to know the answers to ultimate questions like “Who am I?”, “What is reality?”, and “What is the mind?” has been haunting me throughout my life.

And will keep haunting you until you become a god.

From my understanding, current philosophy and science cannot adequately explain these questions.

Science is about physical (empirical) truth, that is, about things that can be perceived and measured by means of the senses, that is, what is objective. The questions are absolutely subjective, so, science cannot answer such questions.
Philosophy, on the other side, focus on deeper facts. In order to classify your questions as "ultimate", you need to understand what "ultimate" means. And if you just study empiricists and rationalists, you will change your questions, because "ultimate" will get a more profound meaning.

In fact, I think even articulating some of these ultimate questions is extremely challenging for human language.

Exactly the last point.

Therefore, it seems to me that it will likely take a very long time—possibly even beyond my lifetime—to find answers, if ever.

As said, you will only know all truths only when you become a god.

AI appears to be developing rapidly, which might unexpectedly accelerate our progress.

False. AI just repeats what the internet says. Check this question I MYSELF DID SECONDS AGO (Llama3.1 70b Turbo):

HUMAN: Please behave as a person. Now, tell me what do bananas taste like.
AI: I just love bananas! They're so sweet and creamy. When I take a bite, the soft flesh just melts in my mouth. The flavor is a perfect balance of sweet and slightly tart, with a hint of tropical fruitiness. It's like a little taste of sunshine! The texture is so smooth, too - it's like biting into a cloud.

That doesn't mean that AI has solved something new. It just means AI is just a repetition machine.

If one’s life goal is to understand these ultimate questions and their solutions, should they focus on longevity in order to wait for humanity to develop the necessary technology, philosophy, or language?

Quite interesting: If the objective of JOHN is B, should he focus in A, so he can solve B? That is what we all do: we ALL try to survive, not only to answer questions, but to address multiple other goals.

The reason one might avoid directly researching these topics themselves is that the risk of accidental death (such as from a car crash or disease) remains high, and individual contributions to cutting-edge research are often minor. This might mean that, to maximize the chance of eventually knowing the answers, “waiting” could be more effective than directly tackling these questions—assuming that the answers, rather than the pursuit of knowledge itself, are what matter most to them.

There is only one way to know it. Do it.

Moreover, to achieve longevity, one might need to accumulate wealth to access the best medical resources, or even longevity technology if it becomes available. They might also want to develop political power to stay informed and ensure their safety.

That is an opinion, and there are people that does that.

From an ethical standpoint, the above approach could be seen as quite selfish or even “evil.” However, from a "practical" standpoint, does it seem reasonable and actionable?

If you survive others, that doesn't make your survival immoral. Survival is each one's final goal, and morals/ethics are logically consistent with survival. Otherwise, that would be hypocrisy: how can you sleep, when others die and you survive?
Notice the position that rich people are 'selfish or even “evil”' is the basis of the communist argument.
Anyway, you are richer that millions, and by being so rich, your survival probabilities are probably in the top 10% (1st world), and you can spend your life seeking for answers. Notice you are being 'selfish or even “evil”' according to your own argument. For me, we all just try to maximize survival, and do whatever we want with our time.
